# Why isn't my box shadow showing on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm quite new to React Native and React in general, and I'm stuck on this particular problem:

I followed some tutorials and other answers on other posts there on StackOverflow, but I can't manage to see the border Shadow I set on these "cards". The shadow isn't displayed on my phone.

I hope so of you old wizards of the internet can help me find a solution to this problem, I'd be really grateful.

```
export class Boss extends Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hp: props.hp,
            ap: props.ap,
        };
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
                <View style={[styles.cardBackground , this.state.hp > 0 ?
                    { backgroundColor: 'gold' }
                    : { backgroundColor: 'red' }]}>
                    <View style={styles.cardFrame}>
                        <Text style={styles.cardName}>{this.props.name}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.bossLifeWrapper}>
                            <Button title={'+'} onPress={this.incrementeHP}></Button>
                            <Text style={styles.bossHP}>{this.state.hp}</Text>
                            <Button title={'-'} onPress={this.decrementeHP}></Button>
                        </View>
                        <Text style={styles.bossAP}>{this.state.ap}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.bossPowerLabel}>{this.props.passive}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.cardTextBox}>
                            <Text style={styles.bossPowerLabel}>Pouvoir: {this.props.powerLabel}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.bossEnrageLabel}>Enrage: {this.props.enrageLabel}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cardContainer: {
        width: '80%',
        height: 450,
        backgroundColor: "#171314",
        alignItems:"center",
        borderStyle: "solid",
        borderColor: "black",
        borderWidth: 1,
        margin: '10%',
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 10,
        shadowColor: "white",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 8,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.44,
        shadowRadius: 10.32,
        elevation: 16,
    },
    cardBackground: {
        backgroundColor: '#171314',
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 10,
        zIndex: 0
    },
    cardFrame: {
        zIndex: 1,
        position: 'relative',
        height: '98%',
        maxWidth: '97%',
        left: '1%',
        top: '0.5%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    cardName: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        alignItems:"center",
        borderStyle: "solid",
        borderBottomColor: "grey",
        borderBottomWidth: 5,
        margin: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 5,
        fontSize: 20,
        height: 10
    },
    bossHP: {
        width: '100%',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    bossAP: {
        width: '100%',
        color: 'red'
    },
    bossLifeWrapper: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column"
    },
});
```

Comment: I don't know anything about react native, really, but often when card shadows aren't appearing it's because the card is within another container and the shadows are being clipped by that container. Try putting some margin on your card and seeing if that makes the shadows appear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @BenP. Does a margin in percentage would be enough for that ? Because as you can see in the code, I set the card margin to 10%

Answer (score 0):

have you tried **elevate** in box styles? ex: elevate:10,

Comment: It seems like the proper css property in react native is **elevation**, which I used. At least that's what I find in the docs and what the console tells me when I try to add **elevate** as a css property